# Search list of emails [HaveIBeenPwned]

Tags: email, have-i-been-pwned

I want to search a list of emails, about 150 roughly on the https://haveibeenpwned.com/
website.

Obviously, I do not want to search each address individually, is there a way to upload a list, or format a list to search all addresses at once? I [read the FAQ's](https://haveibeenpwned.com/FAQs) and did not list anything remotely similar to my question.

Comment: So, this begs the question of, how did you come up with your email list?  Are they all from a domain that you control -- if so, you can use their domain search.

Answer (score 7):

If they are all from the same domain, and you have ownership of the domain, you can use [Domain Search](https://haveibeenpwned.com/DomainSearch).

Otherwise, you can feed them into the [API](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2#BreachesForAccount) one-by-one, with curl, python requests, or likewise: `GET https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/{account}`

The API is rate-limited to [1 request every 1.5 seconds](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2#RateLimiting), so it may take awhile, depending on the size of your list.